# Reboot from terminal waiting running apps to quit

Tags: command-line, reboot

Sometimes (~once in a month), my Ubuntu won't wake up from sleep correctly (it just shows black screen instead of asking for password). In these situations I go to first terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and do "sudo reboot now" (or "sudo reboot").

But `sudo reboot` immediately reboots the system, without waiting firefox to exit.

Is there a way to wait until software will quit nicely, waiting at least 10-20 seconds? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64280/what-is-the-difference-between-reboot-init-6-and-shutdown-r-now), `reboot` do not immediately reboots the system, but has a clean-up procedure that also sends the TERM signal to all processes (see the source code linked in the answer).

It is up to the processes receiving the signal to handle that signal and clean-up before exiting.

Alternatively, a somehow softer alternative could be to stop the display manager before the reboot:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo reboot
```